# Add method to webservice (asmx) with a separate assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am managing a few sites that have some very similar functionality. These use a lot of web services. I would like to be able to drop a assembly in the bin directory to add an additional method to the existing functionality. Later I'd like to be able to remove this dll file which would then remove the additional method in the web service.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: No doubt you want to know why, when you could just switch the main assembly file. There are a couple of thoughts: A separate development team could work independently, also I could assure the customer that I would drop in a file to add functionality and then remove it, also it would be nice to provide functionality to existing and deployed websites without having to recompile. This would give some assurance that nothing has changed. The additional functionality would be used for debugging and sanity checks.

Comment: You should put that into the question itself, rather than putting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to asmx, but maybe it will help. My initial thought is to use a web.config key/value pair as a sort of switch to turn on and off the functionality. You can edit the web.config values without recompiling anything quickly and easily. For example, perform the new service like normal if the value is 1 otherwise toss back an error.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="NewServiceSwitch" value="1" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: What I tried so far was to create a new class which overloads  System.Web.Services.WebService. I write my webservice in that compile it and then drop the assembly. It doesn't work until I add the asmx file (which has the content This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!) This almost works. I don't get 404 error messages. I get an error stating: "The file '/website/MyDroppedWebService.asmx' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested."  I think the missing component is a .compiled file. However this has some sort of hash in it

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is possible, 
What I did was to add the new webservice, Exclude this file, compile and publish the site. Next clone the site. On the cloned version change the project name and remove every dependency (perhaps some dependencies are possible didn't try it). I then published the new site. And copied over just the dll, .compiled and asmx files.